# How can I partition records vertically across machines?

Tags: mysql, database-design, partitioning, remote

I recently asked [two questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134789/partition-data-across-databases-machines): (1) how to store and connect partial records in two or more machines, with the record halves correctly associated, and (2) how to determine the increase in time/space complexity due to the use of remote databases/multiple machines. The responses didn't really address the heart of the issue, so I'd like to clarify my questions:

- First, I'm not asking *if* I should do this but rather *the best way* to do it. For example, I want to store a huge family tree with info such as date of birth (DOB), place of birth, mother's maiden name, citizenship/immigration status, ethnic/religious affiliation, and so on for each member, but I want to partition that info across databases (and machines) to reduce the amount of personally identifiable information (PII) exposure that would occur through the breach of a single machine.
- This security measure is not replacing the standard safeguards of encryption, etc. but rather is in *addition* to them. The issue is that databases with those safeguards already in place have still been hacked (recent examples are the Anthem breach, OPM breach, etc.), so, clearly, "standard" isn't enough.
- Data replication is not an option; I do not want *any* server to store the full data from the records at any time. A proxy server may aggregate the data during a query, but at no time should any server actually store the full record. The records queried will obviously be stored at the client side, but if a client is hacked, the only records exposed are those actually queried, not the millions of others that a server might store.

So I'm looking for the best, most efficient way to partition the data found in a record while ensuring that all parts of the record are linked in a query. Example: I create personal records containing DOB, place of birth, mother's maiden name, citizenship status, ethnic/religious affiliation, and medical information, but only the DOB and citizenship status are stored in the tables contained in database 1. Then database 2 contains tables with medical information and mother's maiden name, and so on. The databases are on separate servers so that if one machine is hacked, only *that* part of the record is accessed.

As a client, if I pull a record, I want to acquire *all* information about a single entity, but as noted above, I don't want to *store* all of the info of any record in a single database or server.

Does anyone have suggestions for the best ways to do this? I'm also interested in how to test the increase in time/space complexity due to the use of remote databases/multiple machines.